# Passing a Controller action parameter to Excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, controller

How Do I pass a parameter from a controller action to excel? I open an excel file using Response.Redirect in a controller action, but want to pass a parameter "id" to Cell "A1" of "Sheet1"

Here is my controller Action:

```
    public ActionResult LaunchStudentBook(string id)
    {
        var stdno = student.StudentTable.Where(a => a.StudentNumber == id);

        Response.Redirect("~/StudentBook/StudentBook.xlsm");

        return View(stdno );

    }
```

Comment: 1) You are both redirecting and returning a view.  They are mutually exclusive (I believe the `Redirect` takes precedence)  2) What do you mean, "pass a parameter" to a cell?  You are having the user download your linked .xlsm file.  Do you mean to say that the behavior you desire is that after they download the file, it modifies the excel spreadsheet after the fact and changes the values in some of the cells? (not going to happen)

Comment: 1) OK
2) Yes, I want to insert the "id" parameter into cell "A1" of "StudentBook.xlsm" and open that. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet to solve this problem is to modify the excel spreadsheet on the server and send back that modified document to the client.  This will involve several independent steps:

1. Get the [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library, a highly regarded (and open source) API for reading and writing Excel files.
2. Use that library to read from `StudentBook.xlsm`.  This will parse the file into an object model that you can then manipulate using EPPlus.  i.e.  This is how you will "insert the 'id' parameter into cell `A1`".
3. Use EPPlus to write the new document to a `MemoryStream`
4. Create an action in your controller that will send this stream back to the client via a `FileStreamResult`.

You should take a stab at all this and then ask new SO questions as you start implementing them.  However, if you respond here, I'll try to help if I can.

Comment: Thanks for helping Kirk. Can we not do this by passing the "id" to a query string? and then have excel pull it using QueryTables.Add?

Comment: No, you cannot.  Imagine what happens when the user downloads your Excel file.  1) He clicks on a link you've provided.  2) You send back the contents of your Excel file such that the user downloads the file and stores it on his hard drive.  Once the file reaches the hard drive, query strings play no part in anything whatsoever.  Query strings can only influence what *you* do on the server.  It cannot influence what happens to the user on his computer. 3) Once the file is downloaded, what is supposed to run the code that invokes  `QueryTables.Add`?

Comment: It's just a dumb file, and even if it were technologically possible to do what you want, it would be a gross security violation.  Macros in Excel have a lot of power and a virus could easily be written for it.  Your users certainly wouldn't want arbitrary code running on their machine.  Trust me, the approach I laid out in my answer is exactly what you should be doing to solve this problem, and it has the benefit that it will familiarize you with a lot of important concepts and technologies.

Comment: Ok, I will try the EPPlus option. But, Would it help if the excel file was opened directly from server? and not from a hard drive? Would QueryTables.Add work then?

Comment: So this is a web server.  What could it mean to open it directly from the server?  Having the user download the file to open it -- that's as close as you're going to get.  And *what* would execute `QueryTables.Add`?  Where would you put that line of code?

Comment: Yes, user will open it from a web server. Regarding executing QueryTables.Add, May be from the excel file, on WorkBook.Load or Activate event. The only thing I am struggling with is adding that "id" parameter in the QueryTable.Add url string. I am storing the excel file within a folder in my VS project, and launching it via Response.Redirect(~/ExcelFile/Excel.xls). Could we somehow append "?id=1" to exel file name and then have some function(fullname) which extracts the "id" and adds it to QueryTables.Add url? The function would be in the Excel file being launched. Is this possible?

Comment: @user, maybe that would work.  When you download the file, is the query string still saved with the file name?  If not, you'll have to use something other than Redirect -- you'll want to use a different result type that lets you customize the file name of the downloaded file.  Something like `StudentBook.1.xlsm`.  Then you could in principle write some excel code to do what you want.  Keep in mind, this might be represented as a security risk to the user since it will require running code on a document downloaded from the internet.

Comment: @user793468 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1252/discussion-between-kirk-woll-and-user793468)

Comment: Yes, the query string will be saved with the file name. I think for now, security is not an issue. I want to get this working soon.
What changes do I need in my controller action to do this?

Comment: You can just append the query string in your redirect command.  `Response.Redirect("~/StudentBook/StudentBook.xlsm?id=5");`.  What happens when you do that?

Comment: but id is not always 5. It can be anything. its an user input.

Comment: @user, yes, that was an example.  So, `Response.Redirect("~/StudentBook/StudentBook.xlsm?id=" + id);` assuming you have a variable named `id` that you got from user input.

Comment: But then how would I get that id into cell A1 of sheet 1?

Comment: @user, I have no idea how to write Excel code.  So if you think there's a way, go for it.  I outlined how I would do it.

Comment: ok, I will try the response.redirect method like following:
Get the id into file name some how and then after opening it, in ecel extract the id from file name on workbook.open event. will keep you posted if this works. Thanks for all the help! :)